# How to write Observable<Buffer> to file using a Vert.x pump?

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

I would like to stream all the emitted Buffers of the *rs* Observable into a file using a [Vert.x 3.5.0 Pump](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/streams/Pump.html) (RxJava2 variant). The example below is somehow not working and I don't know why.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.vertx.core.file.OpenOptions;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.file.AsyncFile;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.streams.Pump;

public class PumpTest {

    @Test
    public void testPump() throws IOException {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        File file = new File("target/test");
        file.delete();

        Observable<Buffer> rs = Observable.just(Buffer.buffer("test123"));
        vertx.fileSystem().rxOpen(file.getAbsolutePath(), new OpenOptions()).map(f -> {
            Pump pump = Pump.pump(rs, f);
            pump.start();
            return f;
        }).map(AsyncFile::flush).subscribe(AsyncFile::close);
        assertEquals("test123", FileUtils.readFileToString(file));
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely overlooked that subscribe is non-blocking and the example code was not actually executed. Once I fixed that I got a ClassCastException. I assume that is a bug. I'll create an issue on github.

Comment: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-rx/issues/123

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of `ReadStream<T>` (first parameter of `Pump.pump`) points to the `ReadStreamSubscriber` class. Which can turn an observable into a readstream.

Instead of `rs`, `ReadStreamSubscriber.asReadStream(rs, Function.identity())` should work in the provided code.

Comment: Is still does not work and this seems rather cumbersome since the asReadStream method returns an io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream which will not be accepted by Pump.pump. The returned read stream would need to be wrapped (RxJava2 wrapper) again in order to conform with the method.

Comment: Using the ReadStreamSubscriber.asReadStream method works when combined with the regular io.vertx.core.streams.Pump.